# setImmediate() function is called after setTimeout() function

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the official sites of nodejs (https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg), it is said that :

> setImmediate() function schedules "immediate" execution of callback
>   after I/O events' callbacks and before timers set by setTimeout and
>   setInterval are triggered.

However in the below code, setTimeout() function executed before setImmediate(). Why?

```
setImmediate(function A() {
  setImmediate(function B() {
    console.log(1);
    setImmediate(function D() { console.log(2); });
    setImmediate(function E() { console.log(3); });
  });
  setImmediate(function C() {
    console.log(4);
    setImmediate(function F() { console.log(5); });
    setImmediate(function G() { console.log(6); });
  });
});

setTimeout(function timeout() {
  console.log('TIMEOUT FIRED');
}, 0)
```

Result:

```
TIMEOUT FIRED
1
4
2
3
5
6
```

I write another example, and `setTimeout` works before `setImmediate` here too.

```
setTimeout(function timeout() {
  console.log('TIMEOUT-1 FIRED');
}, 0)

setTimeout(function timeout() {
  console.log('TIMEOUT-2 FIRED');
}, 0)

setImmediate(function D() { console.log(1); });
setImmediate(function D() { console.log(2); });
setImmediate(function D() { console.log(3); });

setTimeout(function timeout() {
  console.log('TIMEOUT-1 FIRED');
}, 0)

setTimeout(function timeout() {
  console.log('TIMEOUT-2 FIRED');
}, 0)
```

Output:

```
TIMEOUT-1 FIRED
TIMEOUT-2 FIRED
TIMEOUT-1 FIRED
TIMEOUT-2 FIRED
1
2
3
```

Comment: In Node 5.6.0 for the first one I get `1 4 TIMEOUT FIRED 2 3 5 6`

Comment: @metis what version of node.js are you using as there seems to be a bug with some older versions: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6034

Comment: v.4.4.5 it is recommended version for most users on the welcome page of nodejs

Comment: Node 5.3.0 - sometimes `1 4 TIMEOUT FIRED 2 3 5 6` sometimes `TIMEOUT FIRED 1 4 2 3 5 6` - happy investigate : )

Comment: @Pointy: interesting. With 5.10.1 and 6.2.0, I see the same as the OP.  Perhaps it's a platform bug? I'm running OS X 10.11.5 here.

Comment: With v6.2.2 on \*nix, I sometimes get the OP's output, sometimes get the output I expect: `1 4 TIMEOUT FIRED 2 3 5 6`

Comment: What about the second code example? What do you get as output for second sample code?

Comment: The bottom line for me is that relying on scheduling peculiarities like that would be a terribly fragile basis for a system design.

Comment: @Pointy , i came to this point while searching the difference between setImmediate, setTimeout and process.nextTick() . Did you mean that the system should work for each of this? The difference btw them should be ignored?

Comment: I think that Node should work as documented, but *exactly* what the designers intended isn't really clear, and it's obvious that behavior varies. Thus, I would not design my own software in a way that relied on specific platform behavior with these APIs.

Comment: Nice recommendation. What API should you recommend for example?

Comment: I don't know what it is that you're trying to achieve. The timer APIs work well enough for many uses.

Comment: @Pointy , I'm only studying and trying to understand the concepts.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834122/how-is-timing-of-setimmediate-and-settimeout-bound-by-the-performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lets write the above example as following :**

```
var fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile("readme.txt",  function (){
    setTimeout(function timeout() {
      console.log('TIMEOUT-1 FIRED');
    }, 0)

    setTimeout(function timeout() {
      console.log('TIMEOUT-2 FIRED');
    }, 0)

    setImmediate(function D() { console.log(1); });
    setImmediate(function D() { console.log(2); });
    setImmediate(function D() { console.log(3); });

    setTimeout(function timeout() {
      console.log('TIMEOUT-1 FIRED');
    }, 0)

    setTimeout(function timeout() {
      console.log('TIMEOUT-2 FIRED');
    }, 0)})
```

Output :

```
1
2
3
TIMEOUT-1 FIRED
TIMEOUT-2 FIRED
TIMEOUT-1 FIRED
TIMEOUT-2 FIRED
```

**Explanation :**

The order in which the timers are executed will vary depending on the context in which they are called. If both are called from within the main module, then timing will be bound by the performance of the process (which can be impacted by other applications running on the machine).
*For example, if we run the following script which is not within an I/O cycle (i.e. the main module), the order in which the two timers are executed is non-deterministic, as it is bound by the performance of the process:*

```
// timeout_vs_immediate.js
setTimeout(function timeout () {
  console.log('timeout');
},0);

setImmediate(function immediate () {
  console.log('immediate');
});
$ node timeout_vs_immediate.js
timeout
immediate

$ node timeout_vs_immediate.js
immediate
timeout
```

*However, if you move the two calls within an I/O cycle, the immediate callback is always executed first:*

```
// timeout_vs_immediate.js
var fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile(__filename, () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timeout')
  }, 0)
  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log('immediate')
  })
})
$ node timeout_vs_immediate.js
immediate
timeout

$ node timeout_vs_immediate.js
immediate
timeout
```

**The main advantage to using setImmediate() over setTimeout() is setImmediate() will always be executed before any timers if scheduled within an I/O cycle, independently of how many timers are present.**

For more info, refer the following link :
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/topics/the-event-loop-timers-and-nexttick.md

Comment: It describing only what written in the main documentation, which is not clear how it's working, how it's bound to the performance? What means `bound to the performance` That's the main question.