# setTimeout(Func, 0) to be executed before setImmediate?

Tags: node.js, settimeout, v8, event-loop, libuv

As per my understanding the setImmediate is executed in the `Check` phase of the event loop. The `Poll` phase schedules the timers to be executed in the `Timers` phase if their minimum threshold is elapsed.

But the following code executes the timer callback before the setImmediate one (not always). How is that possible since the timer should be scheduled in the `Poll` phase and the `Check` phase comes after it ?

Is it something related to that code is executed in the main module, if so how come setImmediate sometimes executed before the timer ?

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('setTimeout');
}, 0);

setImmediate(function() {
  console.log('setImmediate');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setImmediate() function is called after setTimeout() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076585/setimmediate-function-is-called-after-settimeout-function)